# Firebase/Angular: auth-user-not found

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have read all posts regarding this issue but i cant' apply the solutions to my implementation.
I have the following nodes in firebase:
[image]

The service atached to a regular reactive form to register the user

```
export class UserService {

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }


createUser(user:User){
   this.db.list('/users').push(user)
}
```

And then the login:

```
constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private db: AngularFireDatabase,
    private router: Router) { }


  emailLogin(email:string, password:string) {

    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((user) => {
       console.log("user details:",user);
       this.router.navigate(['/home']);
       console.log('Successfully Signed In');
     }).catch((error) => console.log(error));
   }
```

And I get the message: `There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. etc`
But as I read this is some kind of security feature from firebase. So what can I do work this around?

EDIT @Andrei

AuthService:

```
  createUser(email:string, password:string){
    this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((user)=>{
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      console.log('Successfully registered');

    }).catch(error=>console.log(error))
  }

  emailLogin(email:string, password:string) {

    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((user) => {
      localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
       console.log("user details:",user);
       this.router.navigate(['/home']);
       console.log('Successfully Signed In');
     }).catch((error) => console.log(error));
   }
```

The error message remains the same, plus, i dont see any node created on the firebase console

Answer (score 1):

AngularFireAuth stores users in some other internal collection, not users collection that you've created. you should create users with

```
 this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, passwors)
```

not with filling your custom table

Comment: ok, so this method i used I can use for other stuff, like posts?

Comment: your code suites for all models except for authentication